# @NotNull or @NotEmpty is not working as expected spring boot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, controller

Below is the controller method.
Simple plain method without fancy stuff.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/id", produces = "application/json")
public String clusterid(@RequestParam @NotNull List<Long> id, @RequestParam @NotEmpty String country) {

    log.info("Log: {}, {}", id, country);
    return country;
}
```

I am expecting it to throw exception when I send request `curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/omnichannel/cluster/id?id=&country=

logs output

```
NFO 6962 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.o.o.controller.ClusterController       : Log: [],
```

how to handle this so that any of the combination must not pass through if any of the field is empty or null, e.g (country=pk,empty or null ids), (country="", ids=[1]), ((country=, ids=))

Comment: You are better of to bind those to an object and validate that instead of single method arguments. Else you need `@Validated` on the controller as well, which does serve a bit of a different purpose but would, kind of, make it work.

Comment: why it is necessary?
If the requirements are exactly the same as I mentioned.

Comment: find this ticket, 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26841

Comment: Because validating a model object is different (quite different technically) from validating single method arguments. It also gives you more control and a better OO design to your controllers then keep adding method arguments to bind parameters/forms to.

Comment: ok. So no option other than checking those arguments manual if they are null or empty?

Comment: Have you actually **read** my initial comment... -> *you need `@Validated` on the controller, as well*... Although I would strongly suggest to create a form object to bind the properties to instead of validating request parameters.

Comment: yeah I get it, but I cannot use object. And I tried @Validated before posting the question for a single argument it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use an object? `@Validated` will work as that will create a proxy for the controller. Do you actually have an validation implementation on the classpath? You should use `spring-boot-starter-validation` only adding an API will do nothing (and you have the risk of using the wrong API like JakartaEE instead of JavaEE).